# One PHP code file to upload images from all 10,000,000 users is enough or more PHP files should be there

Tags: php, post

I have a php code on Apache server and the PHP code is there to upload images to the server
the users can upload images via an Android application which communicates with the mentioned PHP code (http post)

Now there are 2 options available for me:
1 - I apply all users with just one address for the mentioned PHP code (In the android application)
2 - I categorized the users to 10 groups for example and have 10 PHP files which are exactly the same as the mentioned PHP code for uploading the images and then apply every group of the users with their own address for the mentioned PHP code

The question is if there is any difference?
If so which option is better?

In other words, I mean if all users which may be 10,000,000 users work with just one PHP file on the server to upload their images on the server, isn't there any performance issue?

Comment: Remember, one PHP script can be run 10,000,000 times all at the same time. Each user will cause a new execution of that one script to happen on the server. So Option 1 is the way to go

Comment: Option 2 does not improve performance one bit. It would introduce maintainability issues however, with keeping your ten script files identical, once you need to make changes/fix a bug. Forget you ever considered this as an option, it isn’t really one to begin with.

Comment: ___If all 10,000,000 users___ attempt to upload an image ___all at the same time___ all servers would struggle. Luckily that is very very unlikely.

Comment: you can think of scaling your infrastructure using  more than one server that is running behind a load balancer so that the load of users will be split between different resources. but inside the same server it is completely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we upload, processor is merely a contributor here, most of the work would be done by disks or memory, so no, 2nd option would not improve performance, it might only decrease the performance..